# How to create a product with multiple variables for set a prices

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set, tierprice

I am struggling trying to create a product in magento with diferent prices
We will sell travel package but the price have to change in this 3 cases.

- Season (more expensive in hight season)
- 3 diferents accomodations (standar, confort and luxury)
- and the price change depending the amount of person in the travel(this I know that I can do it in advanced pricing)

Comment: "Season (more expensive in highest season)" -> set the highest price to the product and use catalog or cart price rules to reduce the price as per your will/required dates. "3 different accommodations (standar, comfort and luxury)" -> Create a custom option "accommodation" where "comfort" and "luxury" is an option with price-relevance.
Or, create a bundle product - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-bundle.html. Inspect the docs about the different product  types magento offers, I'm quite certain your requirement can be build out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for yor answer, I wonder if is possible to put dates with magento(like a calendar) , or do I need a booking extension instead`?